# How to override list_editable save?

Tags: django

```
class MenuPromoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_editable   = ('position', 'sort_by', 'sort_number')
    list_display    = ('id','product', 'category', 'label', 'sort_by', 'position', 'sort_number')
    raw_id_fields   = ('product', 'category')
    list_filter     = []
    ordering        = ('position','sort_number')
    fieldsets       = [
        "Position and Sorting", {
            'classes': ('grp-collapse grp-open',),
            'fields': ['position', 'sort_by', 'sort_number']
        }),
        "Data", {
            'classes': ('grp-collapse grp-open',),
            'fields': ['url', 'label', 'title', 'css', 'product', 'category']
        }),
    ]
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # do something
        super(MenuPromoAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(Menu_Promo, MenuPromoAdmin)
```

I tried that, but it simply doesn't work for "mass save"

[image: This one]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save_model` works for a single object. For multiple objects use [`save_formset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset).

Example:

```
class MenuPromoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        # get all the objects in the formset
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)

        for instance in instances:
            # do something ...

            instance.save()
```

Comment: It is old but works yet